# Pandas dataframe apply refer to previous row to calculate difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have the following pandas dataframe containing 2 columns (simplified). The first column contains *player names* and the second column contains *dates* (`datetime` objects):

```
  player    date
  A         2010-01-01
  A         2010-01-09
  A         2010-01-11
  A         2010-01-15
  B         2010-02-01
  B         2010-02-10
  B         2010-02-21
  B         2010-02-23
```

I want to add a column *diff* which represents the time difference in days *per player*. The result should look like this:

```
  player    date            diff
  A         2010-01-01      0
  A         2010-01-09      8
  A         2010-01-11      2
  A         2010-01-15      4
  B         2010-02-01      0
  B         2010-02-10      9
  B         2010-02-21      11
  B         2010-02-23      2
```

The first row has `0` for diff, because there is no earlier date. The second row shows `8`, because the difference between `2010-01-01` and `2010-01-09` is eight days.

The problem is not calculating the day-difference between two `datetime` objects. I am just not sure on how to add the new column. I know, that I have to make a `groupby` first (`df.groupby('player')`) and then use `apply` (or maybe `transform`?). However, I am stuck, because for calculating the difference, I need to refer to the *previous row* in the apply-function, and I don't know how to do that, if possible at all.

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**
After trying both proposed solutions below, I figured out that they did not work with my code. After much headache, I found out that my data had duplicate indices. So after I found out that I have duplicate indices, a simple `df.reset_index()` solved my issue and the proposed solutions worked. Since both solutions work, but I can only mark one as correct, I will choose the more concise/shorter solution. Thanks to both of you, though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
df['difference'] = df.groupby('player')['date'].diff().fillna(0)
```

This gives the new timedelta column with the correct values:

```
  player       date  difference
0      A 2010-01-01      0 days
1      A 2010-01-09      8 days
2      A 2010-01-11      2 days
3      A 2010-01-15      4 days
4      B 2010-02-01      0 days
5      B 2010-02-10      9 days
6      B 2010-02-21     11 days
7      B 2010-02-23      2 days
```

(I've used the name "difference" instead of "diff" to distinguish the name from the method `diff`.)

Comment: this looks good, however, i get this error: `File "<string>", line 17, in diff / ValueError`. Maybe some problem in my data? My 'date' column definitely contains datetime objects. I just double checked.

Comment: @beta: that's strange, I'm not sure what that error is indicating if your column is of datetime64 type - are you using a current version of pandas?

Comment: the type of the column is `<type 'datetime.date'>` and I am using pandas version `0.16.1`.

Comment: In that case it might be necessary to change the type first; you could try `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and then see if the method works.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Still the same error. But the datatype of the column now is `<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>`. Is this wanted?

Comment: What does `df['date'].dtype` show? It's possible that there are some strange values in your column that are causing problems, but it's difficult to say without seeing more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93906/discussion-between-beta-and-ajcr).

Answer (score 5):

another way if you want to implement it manually is to do the following

```
def date_diff(df):
    df['difference'] = df['date'] - df['date'].shift()
    df['difference'].fillna(0 ,inplace = True)
    return df

In [30]:
df_final = df.groupby(df['player']).apply(date_diff)
df_final
Out[30]:
player  date    difference
A   2010-01-01  0 days
A   2010-01-09  8 days
A   2010-01-11  2 days
A   2010-01-15  4 days
B   2010-02-01  0 days
B   2010-02-10  9 days
B   2010-02-21  11 days
B   2010-02-23  2 days
```

Comment: I get `raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")`. Do you know why? I just looked at the `df` which is returned in `date_diff(df)` and it looks fine. I guess there is then some problem with the indices... But I cannot solve it..

Comment: I suggest that you apply the function on a subset of data for example the first `100` row if it worked then increase the subset until you get the error and know which rows specifically in your data set causes the issue

Comment: thanks for the hint. I just tried `df.head(2).groupby(df['player']).apply(date_diff)` and it also does not work. What is the duplicate axis?

Comment: yes. I am really desparate already. this should be easy, yet I cant figure out my problem.

Comment: can you post the complete error message and stack trace

Comment: @ajcr's answer should work. As long as everything is datetime64. I'd use that instead of this.

Answer (score 3):

`shift()` is a good function, however, if you need to **avoid data duplication**, I would suggest following method.

```
def date_diff(row):
    index = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    if index == 0:
        return np.nan
    prev_row = df.iloc[index - 1]
    return row['date'] - prev_row['date']

df['difference'] = df.apply(date_diff, axis=1)
```

Comment: You did not pass 'row' argument to the 'date_diff' function. Why is that so ?